# List controls C#

Tags: c#, custom-controls

I'm working on something like a download manager on C#, and I need to implement a download list that has to support the following features:

1] The list should support scrolling
2] All the list elements have a url, and some other data + icon

 3] Selection, and multiple selection.

How can I implement this kinda of list? I there an already created control I can use?
I started to implement it using a flowLayoutPanel and custom controls for all the list items and handling the Click events of the custom control. I'm not sure that custom creating this would be the right way to go.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using WPF / Windows Forms?

Comment: @Kieren, the FlowLayoutPanel is a WinForms component, so I'd *guess* the OP is after WinForm ideas/components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using WinForms, you can use a [`ListView` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx), which supports these features as standard.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DataGridView` and implement custom cells/columns for it by inheriting from `DataGridViewColumn`and `DataGridViewCell`.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use WPF, you can use a ListView, with scrolling options enabled, with a GridView on top of it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx